# Problem in Apache POI for reading a Excel

Tags: java, apache-poi

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.lang.Iterable;

public class ReadExcel {
public static String fileToBeRead = "C:/Documents and Settings/Developer/Desktop/Anand   exmps/Anand.xls";
public static void main(String argv[]) {
try {
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(fileToBeRead));
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    //HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(0);
    //HSSFCell cell = row.getCell((short) 0);
    for (Row row : sheet) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
        System.out.println("THE TOP LEFT CELL–> "+ cell.getRichStringCellValue());
    }
}

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("!! Bang !! xlRead() : " + e);
}   

}

}
```

The following error occurs when compiling the above program. What must be th reason? Please fix. Am  a beginner in java.

```
 ReadExcel.java:16: cannot find symbol
 symbol  : class Row
 location: class ReadExcel
            for (Row row : sheet) {
                 ^
 ReadExcel.java:17: cannot find symbol
 symbol  : class Cell
 location: class ReadExcel
            for (Cell cell : row) {
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to import the `Row` and `Cell` classes.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
```

---

**Resources :**

- [HSSFSheet.getRow(int) returns a Row](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#getRow(int))
- [Row iterates on Cell](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html)

Comment: And if he uses Eclipse (or Netbeans) there should have been a warning or an auto-import option :)

Comment: In POI jars, download it on the POI project page, or via maven.